# Single domain forward DNSMASQ

Tags: dns, wildcard, dnsmasq

Hi I need to spoof single domain only not wildcard for example www.google.com and google.com "only" . but with my config client when visit xx.google.com it's respond to 192.168.0.1   ..
my config so far

```
port=53
cache-size=10000
no-negcache
server=8.8.8.8
server=4.2.2.2
server=8.8.4.4
listen-address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
interface=ens160
#log-queries
all-servers
dns-forward-max=3000
domain-needed
bogus-priv
address=/google.com/192.168.0.1
address=/www.google.com/192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Try `host-record=google.com,192.168.0.1`